# QT не может найти lineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

QT не может найти lineEdit.
Я пытаюсь забрать текст из lineEdit так: `ui->lineEdit->text()` Причём он не видит и не выводит lineEdit и даже когда я пытался вставить данную функцию в groupBox он не смог найти и его.

Comment: Если lineEdit на форме, просто очистите и пересоберите проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если lineEdit на форме, просто очистите и пересоберите проек

Comment: Эм... Помогло? )